# "над вязаньем" или "над вязанием"?

Tags: морфология

Как правильно: "над вязаньем" или "над вязанием"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По современным правилам правильно "над вязанием".

However:

> Чередование И // ноль звука (лить – льет, бить – бьет, Мария – Марья, собрание - собранье) связано с наличием в древнерусском языке редуцированного И, который в слабой позиции утратился. Данное чередование широко представлено в словах с односложным корнем:
>
> вить – вьет,
>   шить – шьет,
>   пить – пьет.
>
> Произношение -ия, -ие на конце существительных долгое время поддерживалось церковно-славянской и книжной традицией, поэтому чередование -ия // ья; -ие // -ье сохраняется и в настоящее время, при этом формы на -ье носят разговорный оттенок, формы на -ья свойственны некоторым русским именам, ср.:
>
> житие – житьё,
>   участие – участье,
>   известие – известье,
>   объятия – объятья,
>   крещение – крещенье,
>   Наталия – Наталья,
>   Дария – Дарья.

http://www.proza.ru/2013/07/24/532

*-ье* также распространено в поэтических текстах, когда автор стремится сохранить размер или (в современной поэзии) придать тексту архаично-лирический оттенок. Возможны также замены нормативного *-ье* на *-ие*, они придают тексту архаично-возвышенную окраску и используются чаще всего в сатирических целях.